# VirtualBox redirects to localhost when loading JetBrains Upsource

Tags: windows, apache, virtualbox, jetbrains-ide, upsource

I've hit a brick wall and can't get past it as there isn't too much information out there on this problem. I have a VirtualBox on my Windows machine running Ubuntu with JetBrains Hub and Upsource installed on it. For making it public I am using apache2. I am able to run 'upsource.sh start' and start upsource ok, however when I try to access the website from an external network, the page gets stuck at 'Loading...' and then fails with '[name of my virtual box] server DNS address could not be found.'.

I am able to access the site from the internal network and everything works fine. I am forwarding a port from my public IP to the virtualbox port that is listening for JetBrains Upsource.

My hint is that the virtualbox is redirecting to itself and the client on the external network cannot reach that address. I am unfamiliar with apache so I'm not sure that it's configuration is setup properly. If anyone has run into this problem and fixed it or if anyone knows how to begin to debug/fix this... I'm all ears.

Thank you guys.

EDIT: The server seems to be hanging when the request for OAuth2 is made. Its making request to the virtualbox's local address rather than the public ip.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who runs into the problem in the future, I had to reinstall and put in the correct base-url. I'm guessing I was missing some properties that I needed to re configure and I could not find anywhere what all properties that I could configure.